# Is it possible to load accessibility extension only for particular div

Tags: javascript, accessibility, mathjax

Is it possible to enable explore menu only for a part of a page(using id or class name).
below is the configuration we normally use to enable explore(accessibility).
We are using mathjax version 2.7.4

```
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
        extensions: ['[a11y]/accessibility-menu.js'],
        messageStyle: 'none',
        menuSettings: {
            explorer: true
        }
    });
```

Comment: No, there is no mechanism to restrict the menu to certain expressions.  Can you say why you would not want the explorer menu for *all* mathematical expressions?

Comment: Yeah agreed thanks, there is no other way than using iframe I believe. thanks